# Undefined method or variable error (Rails)

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

So, I have Rating

```
class Rating < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name
  has_many :parties
end
```

And Party, which belongs to Rating

```
class Party < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :rating_id
  belongs_to :rating
end
```

In show.html.erb for rating view

```
 <%=  @rating.parties %>
```

To show all parties, which belong to this rating.

Error:

```
undefined method `parties'
```

I don't get why, if I defined that party model belongs to rating. Have seen stuff like that in examples.

Comment: Please post the **complete** error message. Are you sure `@rating` is not nil?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its coz you have just defined the relation between both the tables but you dint create an attribute which holds the :party so it reports as error.

Try this and see.

```
class Rating < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :party
  has_many :parties
end
```

and call somthing like:

`@rating.party` would give the answer that you really need

Hope it helps!